# How can I get information about malloc()'s behavior?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm wrapping `malloc()` for some reason. I would like to have some (system-specific, at-run-time) information beyond what I can get by merely calling it. For example:

- What's the minimum alignment `malloc()` is using for allocation?
- When allocating a specific stretch of memory, how much did it *actually* allocate (this could theoretically be more than the amount requested)?
- Whether (assuming no other concurrent operations) a `realloc()` will succeed with the same original address or require a move.

Note: I'd like as portable as answer as possible, but a platform-specific answer is still relevant: Linux, Windows, MacOs, Un*x.

Comment: See `max_align_t`

Comment: There can't be any portable way to know, as it is  not standardized.

Comment: If you are "wrapping" `malloc()`, code can keep track and access data for questions 2 & 3.  Better wrap `free(), realloc(), calloc()` too.

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know *why*?

Comment: Also *.. but a platform-specific answer is still relevant...* Which platform?

Comment: @chux: No, I can't. malloc() doesn't tell you how much it allocated; you can at most track what you've asked for.

Comment: The answer for the first question is available. Since `malloc` has to return memory aligned for any scalar type, it's alignment is going to be on the boundary of biggest scalar type. Answer to other questions is not possible to get without completely reimplementing malloc - which is, indeed, possible.

Comment: This is specific to the malloc implementation. You should browse the documentation of your malloc implementation

Comment: @Justin: Of course it is, but _getting_ this information doesn't need to be.

Comment: @SergeyA How do you know which scalar types are supported?

Comment: @EugeneSh., well, that's something you have to know for your implementation, I guess.

Comment: Please note that the question does not insist on a portable way (which, indeed, does not exist), but explicitly asks for a platform-specific way, if any.  I, for one, would be interested to know of any platform-specific ways, too, because this question comes up all the time, because sometimes, being able to do these things would be truly useful.

Comment: @SergeyA Isn't it catch 22?

Comment: @EugeneSh., the question says system-specific answer is OK, so this is a system-specific answer.

Comment: @SergeyA won't it be easier just to hardcode these things to the system-specific values?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes. I was suggesting what those should be hardcoded **to**.

Comment: For GNU, see https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Summary-of-Malloc.html .  I don't see much there corresponding to what you're asking.

Comment: On [Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) and [Linux](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html), there are environment variables that affect the behavior of `malloc`.  This isn't what you're asking for, but may help you track down other details.

Comment: I suppose this is where you roll your own allocator

Comment: @PasserBy I was really tempted to give a similar answer :)

Comment: @paddy: Link to that?

Comment: (nods head) How weird is SO, where you can get 3 upvotes, a nice answer and 20 comments, and at the same time 3 downvotes and a close vote, on something which isn't a meta post.

Comment: @einpoklum do you mean apart from the two links I gave?

Comment: The "portable" part of the question cannot rely just on the operating system.  The compiler and perhaps even the particular implementation of the standard library contribute to the exact behavior of malloc.

Comment: As to how much did it actually allocate, there are a lot of ways to interpret that.  Do you want to count separate allocations that may be used for tracking the state of the allocator?  If a small allocation triggers the actual allocation of a big block that may later be used to satisfy other allocations, do you want to count the entire block?  Do you want to track memory lost to fragmentation?

Comment: @SergeyA Disagree with [boundary of biggest scalar type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468282/how-can-i-get-information-about-mallocs-behavior?noredirect=1#comment77897689_45468282).  Is it not the _size_ of the type that matters, it is the maximum _alignment_ need of the various types.  Alignment requirements may be less than the size.

Comment: This problem has been solved in many ways before.  Unless code's needs are very unique, existing wrappers for allocation functions exist.  Basic ones are a mid-level programming task, but better ones exist in libraries - out there.

Comment: @chux: Most problems presented on SO have been solved before in various libraries... actually I have a potentially valid motivation to not use one of them but it's completely outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 5):

glibc implements `malloc_usable_size`, which returns the actual allocation size available for application use.  Some alternative `malloc`s implement it as well.  Note that glibc can perform a non-moving `realloc` even if the requested new size is larger than the one `malloc_usable_size`, so it is not useful for this purpose.

For the other things you are asking, there are no clear answers.  Theoretically, `malloc` should provide memory at least aligned to `_Alignof (max_align_t)`, but many implementations do not do this for various reasons:

- `max_align_t` comes from a compiler such as GCC and thus reflects the compiler's view of the world, and not what `malloc` provides (see [glibc malloc is incompatible with GCC 7](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21120) for an example).  The C standard assumes a uniform implementation, but in practice, the compiler, the C run-time library, and even `malloc` are separate components, built from different sources, and on different release cycles, so they can fall out of sync, and a compile-time constant such as `_Alignof (max_align_t)` will rarely accurately reflect what `malloc` does at run-time.
- Providing the ABI-mandated 16 byte alignment on x86-64 for allocations of 8 or 4 bytes is wasteful.
- A `malloc` implementation may have internal constraints which result in larger alignment then what is required by the architecture specification.  Applications obviously cannot rely on that, but it is still observable.

Your question about non-moving `realloc` does not even have a proper answer: For a multi-threaded program, another thread might place an allocation which blocks the enlargement of the current allocation between the determination of the resize limit and the actual `realloc` call.  A non-moving version of `realloc` could be a useful addition, but the interface would be quite different (probably something along the lines of *please resize to this maximum value if possible without moving the block, otherwise return the largest possible size* or something like that).

Comment: Any implementation which doesn't align as per standard is non-conforming.

Comment: `malloc_usable_size` is returning the size which is corresponding to the parameter passed to `malloc` + plus the alignment, and not the actual memory usage (including the metadata - not sure if that what was asked, though)

Comment: @Eugene, it's not size plus alignment, but size plus the tail due to internal fragmentation. It's not the full overhead, but I'm not sure if the question was about that. Attributing the full overhead to a single allocation is in general impossible.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Actually I might interested in both these things, but good point.

Comment: Florian, if glibc malloc is incompatible with C-standard malloc in the max_align_t value, how `max_align_t` help me at all?

Comment: @einpoklum, it does not. `max_align_t` is useless. The C standard assumes that there is just a single C implementation, but in reality, you have a compiler, a C library, and perhaps even a separate malloc, all from different sources and on different release cycles. And the alignment bugs aren't even fixed over time due to performance concerns.

Comment: `max_align_t` comes from the C spec.  `malloc()` must _at least_ align to that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a portable answer to these questions, your best bet is to implement your own allocation scheme.  It would be safer to not use the names `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()`, `strdup()`, etc. because you might run into problems with dynamic name resolution, even if your reimplementation of the standard functions is conformant.

Any source code you control could be made to call your allocator by defining a set of macros at the head of every module (via a common header file).

Using system specific tricks to retrieve information from the allocator's metadata is risky because your program will bind to the C library dynamically, so it is possible that such structures change from one system to another, even for the same operating system.

Re-implementing `malloc()` in terms of lower level systems calls such as `mmap()` or other system specific stuff seems deceptively simple, but it is a lot of work to make it correct, stable, efficient and reliable.  You should look at available proven alternative implementations of `malloc` and try and tailor them to your needs.

Comment: This is a valid point, I suppose, but I don't want to go there.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no `free` lunch in this field, you have to brace and enter the arena (and crush'm ;-)

Comment: There are reasonably portable freely available malloc implementations which provide the desired interfaces (more or less). Rolling your own would be an over-reaction imho.

Comment: @rici: I agree with you, that's exactly my advice.